# Cannot solve ** Unable to merge dex error **

Tags: android, gradle, dex

I know this question has been asked many times and I searched through them but couldn't solve my problem. I added the
 `multiDexEnabled true`

and also the

`implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'`

as some answers suggested but couldn't solve it. Can anyone please help me ,because since this issue occurred ,I'm stuck .

The error is   `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex`

My build.gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.flashcardapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

//pin edittext library
implementation 'com.alimuzaffar.lib:pinentryedittext:1.3.1'

// glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

//amazon aws
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.22'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.13'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.22'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.6.22'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.6.22'
implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true }
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.323'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by removing unused libraries and then clean and rebuild project ,as Redman suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

And after this clean and rebuild your project. Hope this works :)

Comment: I added it and also clean and rebuild project but wasn't working ,but then removed the unused libraries and now working .Thanks !!

Comment: Mark answer as  correct if it helps you :) . Thanks.!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by adding MaxHeapSize into gradle file.

```
android {
...
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
   }
}
```

I hope this will help you to solve the problem.

Comment: I added it and also clean and rebuild project but wasn't working ,but then removed the unused libraries and now working .Thanks !!

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer then accept my answer by clicking on the right arrow shows on the left of my given answer. Thanks.